# How should I create my Data Mappers/Domain Objects/Services?

Tags: php, oop, model-view-controller

So I'm making this web application in PHP, and I wanted to make a decent model layer (as much as possible) with Domain Objects and Data Mappers, all orchestrated by Services.

And now I'm thinking, how should I create my objects?

### Factories?

But then:

- I'd have to use reflection to actually enforce if an object implements a certain interface (`DataMapper` usually. The others don't have set methods they need to implement; I don't want to rely on names, because naming conventions change).
- I'd have to defy the law of demeter by passing the factories into the ServiceFactory which would then only pass it to the service it creates.

### The `new` keyword?

But then:

- I'd have problems testing the code in isolation.
- Feels too tightly coupled.

### Anything else?

I don't know, that's why I'm asking! :P

What should I do? Is there a better approach to this?

Comment: You can use typehinting to enforce types without using reflection.  I'd recommed using something like Doctrine2 to abstract all of this away for you.

Comment: I usually take a factory (w/o reflection) and use [spl_autoload](http://php.net/spl-autoload) to catch such dependencies. Of course this only works if you have some naming conventions (like PSR-0)

Answer (score 1):

Brian Vanderbusch's comment hints at the best way. You should use Dependency Injection to inject the mapper you need. However, to reduce coupling you should also type hint the most basic type, usually an interface.

How you actually inject the Data Mapper into your (presumably) model layer doesn't really matter. A Dependency Injection Container can store all the metadata about which classes need which data mappers and automatically inject the dependencies for you. However, without using a DIC, the top level of your code should, at the most basic level, look like this:

```
    $model = new ProductsModel(new ProductsDataMapper(new Db('localhost', 'u', 'p', 'd')));
```

of course the mapper and database would almost certainly be shared between other objects in the real world and you'd pass in the references to the existing instances. If you need multiple mappers in the model layer, pass them all in as constructor arguments.

The key here is to build the entire object graph at the very top level of the application rather than worrying about locating them after the fact. This is the premise of inversion of control, which you can think of as building the structure from inside out.

Comment: You (and apparently Brian as well) misunderstand how a model (or rather, a service) should actually work. A service may create and destroy as many Domain Objects or Data Mappers as it needs (for registeration, I'd create one `User` object, but for complex data handling, I may create 50 Domain Objects and 10 Data Mappers to map them all to/from the database.

Comment: I disagree, the mappers themselves should not be transient in nature. The domain objects can be created/destroyed but the mappers should be persistent (or last at least exist as long as the services which requires them does).  If a single services is creating 10 different mappers, I'd suggest that hints at a very poor separation of concerns. If (for simplicities sake) each mapper relates to one database table what can you possibly need to access from 50 tables within one class?

Comment: Why would your magical "ProductsModel" be aware of saving itself ?

Comment: It was just an example name of the service which requires the use of the datamapper. A datamapper will deal with loading/saving records, the service/model layer will use datamappers and store the logic for actually processing the data. Feel free to edit the answer with something more appropriate.

Comment: naah .. I will jut make some tea and write up my own answer .. though the damned thing will take an hour again =/

Comment: I guess @tereško is having some quality teatime since the hour has passed at this very moment ;)

Comment: @tereško That's one *very* long hour.

Comment: @tereško This is going to be some answer...52,344 hours